# Visual Studio causes blue screen

Tags: visual-studio-2008

On one of our development machines with Visual Studio 2008 SP1, whenever the developer closes Visual Studio, the machine goes to Blue Screen of Death.

Has anyone experienced this problem or know of a solution.

Comment: Which operating system? On XP or later, a blue screen is usually a hardware or driver failure and is not related to a specific application.

Comment: What's the error code, i.e. the underscore-spaced string a few lines down the screen? That'll hint at what the underlying issue could be.

Comment: A specific application might be utilising a certain piece of hardware or a driver in a certain way that causes a blue screen reliably though.

Comment: Microsoft is angry you're closing one of its programs.

Comment: suggest you contact microsoft helpdesk.

Comment: I don't think a program about an application crashing becomes programming-related just by virtue of the fact the application is an IDE. I wouldn't expect questions about MS Word to be answered just because I may use it to edit my code. This is an application issue, suggest you contact MS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, Visual Studio cannot *cause* a BSOD. It's purely user mode code, and only Kernel mode code can cause a BSOD.

Still, I once saw a piece of VPN software crash the system because it had a bug that was triggered by Visual Studio. The VPN software had the ability to monitor what programs you were running, and what DLLs they loaded, and could decide on that basis whether or not to allow you to use the VPN. It did that with a Kernel-mode filter of some sort.

The filter had a bug, which was triggered by the fact that Visual Studio loads as a number of separate components, and often loads components at runtime. This meant the VPN software was being called frequently, which triggered its bug.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We found that some files were missing in the SDK directory, we copied over the 6.0A directory from another machine and the problem went away (after being there for months). Not logical but it works now.

Comment: It's logical if you've got the same problem I had - some program watching file system operations around .dll files; said program having a bug and not having a good time watching all the .dll loads Visual Studio does. In your case, it finally crashes on a file not found result.